# Too few arguments when passing variables between blade files (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-8

I am trying to send user variable from users.show.blade file here:

```
@extends('layouts.myapp')

@section('title', 'User')

@section('content')
<ul>
    <li>Name: {{$user->name}}</li>
    <li>Email: {{$user->email}}</li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{route('posts.index', ['id' => $user->id])}}">Posts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="{{route('users.index')}}">Back</a>
@endsection
```

To an posts.index.blade file for a post here:

```
@extends('layouts.myapp')

@section('title', 'Posts')

@section('content')
<a href="{{route('posts.create')}}">Create Post</a>
<ul>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <p>{{$user}}</p>
        <li><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">{{$post->title}}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endsection
```

By calling the PostController showByUser method:

```
public function showByUser($id){
    $posts = Post::all();
    $user = User::FindOrFail($id);
    return view('posts.index', ['user'=>$user, 'posts'=>$posts]);
}
```

In route:

```
Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'showByUser'])->name('posts.index');
```

I get the following error:

'Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PostController::showByUser(), 0 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected'

I can't figure out where am I not passing the 1 variable is asking for.

Comment: Your route doesn't take a parameter

Answer (score 1):

you have missed `route param` in `post index route` like this way `{id}`

if have optional param than write this way `{id?}` else `{id}`

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'showByUser'])->name('posts.index');
```

you have used same route with `id param` change their name

```
Route::get('/get_posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'showByUser'])->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/view_posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('posts.show'); 
Route::delete('/delete_posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but now I get the 'Undefined variable $user' error :))

Comment: where you get `'Undefined variable $user' error`

Comment: In posts.index file

Comment: check you have value inside `$user` or write `@ before variable like @$user`

Comment: when I am inside users.show it takes their id, and then when i go to the posts.index it just prints on the screen as text @$user

Comment: so what happens after that? you have tried `dd($user)` in controller function?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but nothing happened. I have another route to the same page `Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts.index');`, which is called before the one I previously showed and it seems to take that one instead. The index function is: `public function index()
    {
        //
        $posts = Post::get();
        return view('posts.index', ['posts'=>$posts]);
    }`.

Comment: so into this function you have not passed `$user` variable that's why it will give an error

Comment: I tried commenting the route where I didn't passed $user variable and I receive `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` error

Comment: can you share your route file?

Comment: `Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
Route::get('/users/create', [UserController::class, 'create'])->name('users.create');
Route::post('/users', [UserController::class, 'store'])->name('users.store');
Route::get('/users/{id}', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('users.show');
Route::delete('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');`

Comment: where you get `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST` this error

Comment: `Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'])->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'showByUser'])->name('posts.index');
Route::get('/posts/create', [PostController::class, 'create'])->name('posts.create');
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'])->name('posts.store');
Route::get('/posts/{id}', [PostController::class, 'show'])->name('posts.show');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy');`

Comment: i have update my answer with `route file` change

Comment: if I comment out the first post route, so it calls showByUser, that's when I get that error

Comment: now try with updated route file change and check